# Opencv Variables not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, opencv

I've just started to try opencv. And have run the program successfully on my another computher(have two computers).

I've followed the same installation steps as the computer that have built successfully, but it isn't work it prompt up the error message below, after I've `cmake` and `make` to build the project.

Testing this example here on the official site:
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html#code

```
/home/howard/Documents/opencv/opencv-sample/template_match/template_match.cpp:11:22: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
 char* image_window = "Source Image";
                      ^
/home/howard/Documents/opencv/opencv-sample/template_match/template_match.cpp:12:23: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
 char* result_window = "Result window";
                       ^
/home/howard/Documents/opencv/opencv-sample/template_match/template_match.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/howard/Documents/opencv/opencv-sample/template_match/template_match.cpp:28:30: error: ‘CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE’ was not declared in this scope
   namedWindow( image_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
                              ^
/home/howard/Documents/opencv/opencv-sample/template_match/template_match.cpp:32:26: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
   char* trackbar_label = "Method: \n 0: SQDIFF \n 1: SQDIFF NORMED \n 2: TM CCORR \n 3: TM CCORR NORMED \n 4: TM COEFF \n 5: TM COEFF NORMED";
                          ^
/home/howard/Documents/opencv/opencv-sample/template_match/template_match.cpp: In function ‘void MatchingMethod(int, void*)’:
/home/howard/Documents/opencv/opencv-sample/template_match/template_match.cpp:68:24: error: ‘CV_TM_SQDIFF’ was not declared in this scope
   if( match_method  == CV_TM_SQDIFF || match_method == CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED )
                        ^
/home/howard/Documents/opencv/opencv-sample/template_match/template_match.cpp:68:56: error: ‘CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED’ was not declared in this scope
   if( match_method  == CV_TM_SQDIFF || match_method == CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED )
                                                        ^
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/template_match.dir/template_match.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/template_match.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Do any one know what's happening and how could I fix it?

Comment: `char *` is not for strings that can't be modified.

Comment: It is strange, but you could try prefixing the cv namespace to these constants, e.g. cv::CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE.

Comment: @ypnos same error... it is really strange, but I was wondering, maybe I've install an unstable version. Cause I've git clone the repo from the github. As the instruction on official site: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#getting-the-cutting-edge-opencv-from-the-git-repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found out the problem, it's because I've installed a unstable version, you should not install the opencv from the repo https://github.com/Itseez/openc/ directly, go to the release version and download the latest.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problems using 3.0.0 beta.

Your first line is a C++ warning.  You can get by just ignoring it for now if you're just trying to run the test.  Otherwise use `std::string` and convert it with the `c_str()` method when you need to.  These `char* windowName = "My Window"` lines show up in the OpenCV tutorials a lot.

For the second `namedWindow()` parameter, just use `WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` instead of `CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE`.

For the template matching, you also need to take out the `CV_` prefix and use `TM_SQDIFF`.  Looks like it works for all of the others too (`TM_SQDIFF_NORMED`, `TM_CCORR`, etc.).